# Change the font on odfpy?

Tags: python, fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, odfpy

How can I change the font on odfpy for example, using Arial or comic sans. I've seen some [examples](https://balasankarc.in/tech/using-python-and-odfpy-to-create-open-document-texts.html) but they only use the params "fontsize" and "fontweight". I can't find any example changing the font and the param "font" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Section 5.15.39 in `api-for-odfpy.odt` lists the `style.TextProperties` as:

```
    5.15.39  style.TextProperties
    Requires the following attributes: No attribute is required.
    Allows the following attributes: backgroundcolor, color, condition, country,
 countryasian, countrycomplex, display, fontcharset, fontcharsetasian,
 fontcharsetcomplex, fontfamily, fontfamilyasian, fontfamilycomplex,
 fontfamilygeneric, fontfamilygenericasian, fontfamilygenericcomplex, fontname,
fontnameasian, fontnamecomplex, fontpitch, fontpitchasian, fontpitchcomplex,
 fontrelief, fontsize, fontsizeasian, fontsizecomplex, fontsizerel, fontsizerelasian,
 fontsizerelcomplex, fontstyle, fontstyleasian, fontstylecomplex, fontstylename,
 fontstylenameasian, fontstylenamecomplex, fontvariant, fontweight, fontweightasian,
 fontweightcomplex, hyphenate, hyphenationpushcharcount, hyphenationremaincharcount, language, languageasian, languagecomplex, letterkerning, letterspacing, scripttype,
 textblinking, textcombine, textcombineendchar, textcombinestartchar, textemphasize,
 textlinethroughcolor, textlinethroughmode, textlinethroughstyle, textlinethroughtext,
 textlinethroughtextstyle, textlinethroughtype, textlinethroughwidth, textoutline,
 textposition, textrotationangle, textrotationscale, textscale, textshadow,
 texttransform, textunderlinecolor, textunderlinemode, textunderlinestyle, 
textunderlinetype, textunderlinewidth, usewindowfontcolor.
```

I assume they are accessible in the same way as `fontsize` and `fontweight`, as in:

```
h1style.addElement(TextProperties(attributes={'fontsize':"24pt",'fontweight':"bold" }))
```

Although, I personally have no intention of loading software this old to test it.

Comment: Use `'fontfamily':"Arial"` worked for me, thanks

Comment: @user3476016 My pleasure, welcome to StackOverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers